# How do I enable syntax highlighting for Clojure on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

The default syntax highlighting for Clojure code on Stack Overflow often makes mistakes. [The editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) says the highlighter should use the question tags (e.g. `clojure`) to infer the correct language highlighting mode, but this often doesn't work correctly. For example, see this code:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))

(def data [[1 2 [3]]
           [[4 5] 6]
           [7]])

(def search-result (atom nil))
(defn search-impl
  [goal? data]
  (when (= ::not-found @search-result)
    (if (goal? data)
      (reset! search-result data)
      (when (coll? data)
        (doseq [it data]
          (search-impl goal? it))))))

(defn search [goal? data]
  (reset! search-result ::not-found)
  (search-impl goal? data)
  @search-result)

(dotest
  (println "1 => " (search #(= 5 %) data))
  (println "2 => " (search #(and (integer? %) (even? %)) data))
  (println "3 => " (search #(= [4 5] %) data))
  (println "4 => " (search #(= 99 %) data)) )
```

We see that syntax highlighting is missing for most of the Clojure functions. Also, the hashtag symbol `#` of inline functions such as `#(= 5 %)` is interpreted as the beginning of a comment, and the rest of the line is grayed-out.

How do I get Stack Overflow to correctly highlight Clojure code?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert an HTML comment to identify the source code language. This "language ID comment" is placed before your Clojure code, and informs the syntax highlighter that Clojure code is present.

**NOTE:** A blank line ***must*** separate the HTML language-ID comment from the source code.  A complete example looks like so:

```clj
<!-- language-all: lang-clj -->

    (ns tst.demo.core
      (:use tupelo.test)
      (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))

    (def data [[1 2 [3]]
               [[4 5] 6]
               [7]])

    (def search-result (atom nil))
    (defn search-impl
      [goal? data]
      (when (= ::not-found @search-result)
        (if (goal? data)
          (reset! search-result data)
          (when (coll? data)
            (doseq [it data]
              (search-impl goal? it))))))

    (defn search [goal? data]
      (reset! search-result ::not-found)
      (search-impl goal? data)
      @search-result)

    (dotest
      (println "1 => " (search #(= 5 %) data))
      (println "2 => " (search #(and (integer? %) (even? %)) data))
      (println "3 => " (search #(= [4 5] %) data))
      (println "4 => " (search #(= 99 %) data)) )
```

Note that the language-ID hint `<!-- language-all: lang-clj -->`
 informs the highlighter that ***all*** code blocks are to be interpreted as clojure (not just the following block).  If you have code blocks in more than one language in your post, just drop the `-all` part and put something like the following before ***each*** code block to force the correct highlighting:

First some Clojure code:

```clj
<!-- language: lang-clj -->

    (defn do-stuff [some-arg]
      (let [result (+ 1 2 3 some-arg) ]
        result ))
```

then some HTML source:

```html
<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <html>
      <!-- some html comment -->
      <div>Who knows what comes next...</div>
    </html>
```

followed by a little Python:

```python
<!-- language: lang-python -->

for x in xrange(1, 11):
    for y in xrange(1, 11):
        print '%d * %d = %d' % (x, y, x*y)
```

and wrapping up with some command-line examples (bash/zsh/etc):

```bash
<!-- language: lang-bash -->

#!/bin/zsh
# echo ".zshrc - enter"

export HISTSIZE=1000
export SAVEHIST=1000
export HISTFILE=~/.history

# vi command-line editing mode
bindkey -v

# use sensible globbing (like csh nonomatch)
setopt csh_null_glob

# set prompt string
PS1='%50<>> ..<%~ > '

# echo ".zshrc - exit"
```